# How to check SQL server version in Laravel blade view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server

How to check SQL server versions in Laravel blade file. I want make file system info.
Now i have this:

```
<div>Laravel version:  {{ App::VERSION() }}</div>
<div>PHP version: @php echo phpversion(); @endphp</div>
```

and this give me a view:

```
Laravel version: 5.8.37

PHP version: 7.2.8
```

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-server-info.php maybe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `RAW` query :

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw('SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"') );
```

> You will find additional version details about your installed MySQL
>   software like `innodb_version`, `protocol_version`, `version_ssl_library`
>   and more.

[image]
Reference:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-get-mysql-version

Comment: how can i get value version and version_comment from array $result. When i use @foreach($results as $result) $result->verison @endforeach i get error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. If i use print_r($results); i have view array where is [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => version
            [Value] => 10.2.2-MariaDB
        )

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php echo mysql_get_server_info(); ?>
```

Comment: To use `mysql_get_server_info` first you need to make connection 
 with db `mysqli_get_server_info ( mysqli $link ) : string` https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-server-info.php